# Click link inside table

Tags: html, vbscript, getelementbyid

I am trying to click a navigation link inside a table but I cannot get it to work. I have tried

- `getElementByID`
- `getElementsByClassName`
- `getElementsByTagName`

and all come up empty.

This

```vb
Set tbls = HTMLDoc.getElementByID("tabToggleTable")
```

leaves

```vb
tbls = Nothing
```

Here is the portion from the website I am looking at (specifically `<td title="Provider Accounting Home Page"`):

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <body onhelp="" onload="sfHomePageLoad();" onresize="">
    <div id="pagehider">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="11" cellPadding="0">
      <colgroup>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td id="WorkListsColumn">
        <td id="TasksColumn">
          <table width="100%" height="100%" class="CUI-Table" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="5">
            <tbody>
            <tr height="15" class="CUI-SectionTitleBar">
            <tr height="40%" class="CUI-Section">
              <td style="border-top-color: #6c8cd9; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" class="CUI-Table" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr height="15" class="CUI-SectionTitleBar" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px;">
                    <tr height="100%" class="CUI-Section">
                      <td style="border-top-color: #6c8cd9; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid;">
                        <div id="PrimaryTasksGrid" style="width: 682px; height: 326px; overflow: auto;">
                          <table width="100%" style="background-color: white;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr class="CUI-TableGridLinesRow">
                                <td title="Provider Accounting Home Page" class="CUI-TableGridLinesRow" id=" 39" onmouseover="javascript:colorRow(this)" onmouseout="unColorRow(this)" onmousedown="javascript:colorRowClick(this)" onclick="javascript:nodeOnClick(this);" IgfSessionSecurity="<1" IgfFwdCred="false" IgfText="Provider Accounting Home Page" IgfUrl="../Bin/SmsTntRequest.asp?action=StartBusinessProcess&name=ProviderAccountingHomePage&form=ProviderAccountingHomePage&&GSM=duAuQFBuIBQHBxEpBxP-ALj98ABtQ9rL:XezOC76g7axKlXthZBxb5rrcVbgPa5wMe7QmxBQWL18_" IgfType="2">
                                  <font face="Arial" size="2">
                                    Text -  Provider Accounting Home Page
```

[image: Screenshot of HTML structure]

Answer (score 0):

The `<td>` element with the title "Provider Accounting Home Page" has the ID `39` (with a leading space), so you should be able to select that element like this:

```
Set td = HTMLDoc.getElementById(" 39")
```

**Edit:** so, apparently you posted the exact HTML structure, *except for the minute detail that it's nested in an `<iframe>`*. Which requires you to reach into the iframe to be able to fetch the element you want.

```
Set iframe = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("iframe").Item("tabWell0")
Set td = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById(" 39")
```

Comment: When I try that I get td = nothing

Comment: @cfuson Then either `HTMLDoc` is not an `HTMLDocument` object, or the HTML is different from the sample you posted.

Comment: I can use Set td = HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagname(" div") and get a response, if I try Set td = HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagname(" table")  it again is nothing

Comment: @cfuson Both statements will give you an empty `DispHTMLElementCollection`, since there are no HTML tags with a leading space in their name.

Comment: Sorry there actually is no space - it should read: I can use Set td = HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagname("div") and get a response, if I try Set td = HTMLDoc.getElementsbyTagname("table") it again is nothing

Comment: @cfuson Then your HTML doesn't look like the sample you posted.

Comment: That is the exact this i see when I goto the website(not mine btw) and hit F12.

Comment: I found out more information and re-asked the question accordingly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358956/vbscript-get-to-link-in-table-with-no-name-id

Comment: @cfuson You should edit this question instead of posting a new one.